# c# expander panel not showing up

Tags: c#, xaml

I have code that is supposed to add textblocks to a stack panel that is already created in xaml. I then want to surround that stack panel by an extender. However, the expander is not showing up when I run it at all.

code to add to textblocks (a list of exceptions):

```
public void Update(AggregateException ae)
        {
        StackPanel exceptionsSP = this.ExceptionSP;
        Expander exceptionExpander = new Expander();
        exceptionExpander.Name = "Exceptions";
        exceptionExpander.Header = ae.Message;//The outer exception message
        exceptionExpander.IsExpanded = false;
        exceptionExpander.ExpandDirection = ExpandDirection.Down;
        List<TextBlock> exceptionTexts = new List<TextBlock>();
        foreach (Exception exception in ae.InnerExceptions)
        {
            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = exception.Message;
            exceptionsSP.Children.Add(textBlock);
        }
        exceptionExpander.Content = exceptionsSP;
    }
```

XAML already created:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
    <RowDefinition x:Name="OKButton" Height="111"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="ExceptionSP" Grid.Row="0">
    </StackPanel>

<Button Grid.Row="1" IsCancel="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Height="30"/>
```

Resulting xaml (No Extender):

[image]

Comment: Maybe because it is empty?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the expander in code and then setting the expander's content to the StackPanel that is created in XAML. That doesn't make any sense...the Expander just goes away at the completion of your function. The expander needs to be created in XAML, or you need some sort of ContentPresenter in the XAML to hold the Expander.

Without editing the XAML you could: Ceate a new inner StackPanel, add the items to that, set that as the content for the expander, then finally do `this.ExceptionSP.Content = exceptionExpander`.

This is what the code would look like if you didn't want to change your XAML

```html
public void Update(AggregateException ae)
{
    StackPanel innerSp = new();
    Expander exceptionExpander = new Expander();
    exceptionExpander.Name = "Exceptions";
    exceptionExpander.Header = ae.Message;//The outer exception message
    exceptionExpander.IsExpanded = false;
    exceptionExpander.ExpandDirection = ExpandDirection.Down;
    List<TextBlock> exceptionTexts = new List<TextBlock>();
    foreach (Exception exception in ae.InnerExceptions)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.Text = exception.Message;
        innerSp.Children.Add(textBlock);
    }
    exceptionExpander.Content = innerSp;
    this.ExceptionSP.Content = exceptionExpander;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm not understanding a few concepts. Sorry, new to XAML...

Are you saying that you can't create elements in XAML with C#? I am used to CSS where you can.

What is the concept of why you suggestion works?

If I'm understanding, you would have:
`<StackPanel x:Name="ExceptionSP" Grid.Row="0">`
        `<StackPanel >`
              `<TextBlock></TextBlock>`
       `</StackPanel>`
`</StackPanel>`

Comment: What is the concept of why your suggestion works? Can you show in Xaml what that is? I tried guessing in the comments, but the code doesn't show well. In addition, why does creating a stack panel in c# persist, but creating an expander in c# doesn't persist?

Comment: Yes, you can create elements in code. But in your code, you sorta have things inverted. (the WPF visual tree is more top-down) You create `exceptionExpander` and set its content but it has no parent. You need an element in the xaml to host the expander. Just setting it's content to a child doesn't magically cause it to appear.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks. So that's what I was trying to do in `exceptionExpander.Content = exceptionsSP`. I was trying to set the parent element of the expander to the Stack Panel called ExceptionsSP that was already created in xaml. Is there a way I can do this instead of setting the content without creating additional stack panels?

Comment: Yes `<Expander x:Name="ExceptionExpander" Grid.Row="0"><StackPanel x:Name="ExceptionSP"/></Expander>`. Then you don't need to do anything with the expander in your codebehind, just use the StackPanel.